# Simulate head or tails

Tags: php, random

What's the best way to simulate the concept of flipping a coin in PHP?

I need to random between `true` and `false`.

Is `mt_rand(0, 1)` a good solution?

Comment: What about the coin landing on its edge? :)

Comment: Wow, *between* `true` and `false`. What would that be? Maybe? Sort of? Sometimes? Kinda? It depends?

Comment: It's good. `mt_rand() & 1` is also good.

Comment: @AleksG Haha you're funny! Is there a third boolean? "Maybe"?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Make sure you seed well you random number generator, so you're sure that your result lists are various. Ok, this wasn't a so long answer, after all, but still yes, rolling a random between 0 and 1 looks like the fastest way to have a random true/false value.

Comment: `mt_rand` is automatically seeded. If you don't need your random sequences to be reproducible there's little point in seeding it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on how statistically accurate you need to be. Super-high-quality random number generators use atmospheric noise and other "true" sources of randomness.

But, for the vast majority of cases, yes a simple rand() is fine.